# How to pass variables different from Request and Response in Slim Framework 4

Tags: php, slim

Please tell me how to pass variables different from Request and Response to the called function in Slim Framework 4?

Let me explain with an example what I need. For example, I have a route (`$app->get('/{id}', [Controller::class, 'id']);`) that calls the `id` method in `Controller`.

In `Controller` the function is declared like this: `public function id(Request $request, Response $response): Response`.

I would like to replace `Request` and `Response` with my own variable, which I initialize based on the `id` that is passed as a parameter.

Here is an example of what I need: `public function id(Entity $entity): Response`